# Condição para ignorar arquivos ".min.js"

Tags: gulp, gulpjs, gulpfile

Tenho a seguinte tarefa no meu gulpfile.js que renomeia arquivos **.js** para **.min.js**:

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.scripts.src)
            .pipe(gulpif(prod, uglify()))
            .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scripts.dest));
});
```

Porém, preciso de alguma forma para ignorar o Rename de arquivos que já são ".min.js". Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

substitua o código:

```
return gulp.src(paths.scripts.src)
```

Pelo código:

```js
return gulp.src([
  `${paths.scripts.src}/*.js`,
  `!${paths.scripts.src}/*.min.js`
])
```